# Haskell: Cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ Maybe a

Tags: haskell

I have the following definition of a binary tree and a function that fetches the leftmost element, or return Nothing if the tree is an Empty tree, however it is saying `x` (with type `a`) is an infinite type because it returns `Maybe a`?

Thanks any help would be appreciated :)

```hs
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Eq)

leftistElement :: (Ord a) => Tree a -> Maybe a
leftistElement EmptyTree = Nothing
leftistElement (Node x left _) =
  if left == EmptyTree
    then x
    else leftistElement left
```

```
types.hs:55:10: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ Maybe a
    • In the expression: x
      In the expression:
        if left == EmptyTree then x else leftistElement left
      In an equation for ‘leftistElement’:
          leftistElement (Node x left _)
            = if left == EmptyTree then x else leftistElement left
    • Relevant bindings include
        left :: Tree a (bound at types.hs:53:24)
        x :: a (bound at types.hs:53:22)
        leftistElement :: Tree a -> Maybe a (bound at types.hs:52:1)
   |
55 |     then x
   |          ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: Unless you are looking for extremely liberal elements of the tree, the name you are looking for is `leftestElement` :)

Comment: `leftmostElement` would work best, though.

Comment: a couple of notes that are unrelated to your question: 1) you don't need the `Ord a` constraint in your function, as you never use any comparison among the elements, 2) you would need a weaker `Eq a` constraint because of your `left == EmptyTree`, but even that wouldn't be necessary if you used a `case` expression to check the constructor of `left` rather than relying on `==`.

Comment: Pattern matching is usually preferred to `==` when possible. An elegant implementation that does this might look like `leftmost EmptyTree = Nothing; leftmost (Node x left _) = leftmost left <|> Just x`; or, if performance matters more than elegance, you might write `leftmost EmptyTree = Nothing; leftmost (Node x left _) = Just (go x left) where go x EmptyTree = x; go _ (Node x left) = go x left`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x` has type `a`, but you try to return it as a value of type `Maybe a`. Because `a` is  type variable, though, the type checker attempts to see if there is some instance of `Maybe` that makes `a` and `Maybe a` unify, which leads to the infinite-type error.

Use `pure` (or `Just`) to return a value of the correct type.

```
leftistElement (Node x left _) =
  if left == EmptyTree
    then pure x
    else leftistElement left
```

Comment: Thanks thats really helpful, if I wanted to return an EmptyTree instead of nothing, would that still work?

Comment: You would have to change the return type of the entire function to `Tree a`, as well as return something like `Node x Empty Empty` when you do find a left-most element.